# Possible to inject same stateful session bean instance into multiple other session beans?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Is it possible to make the container inject the same stateful session bean instance into multiple other stateful session beans?

Given the following classes:

```
@Stateful
public class StatefulTwoBean implements StatefulTwo {

    @EJB
    private StatefulOne statefulOne;

}

@Stateful
public class StatefulThreeBean implements StatefulThree {

    @EJB
    private StatefulOne statefulOne;

}
```

In the above example, *StatefulTwoBean* and *StatefulThreeBean* each get injected their own instance of *StatefulOneBean*.

Is it possible to make the container inject the **same instance** of *StatefulOneBean* into both *StatefulTwoBean* and *StatefulThreeBean*?

Comment: What is your application server.

Comment: @Pascal, well, I was once investigating a similar issue, and found that that WebLogic (if I recall correctly) has some ability to achieve what he wants. I was then using Glassfish (which couldn't). So if his app server is glassfish, I could look in the codebase and find something to wokr his issue around :)

Comment: My application server is GlassFish 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this - Stateful beans' isntances are allocated by differentiating the clients that call them. Glassfish (and perhaps others) don't propagate this difference on injected beans. The EJB specification, as far as I remember, isn't clear about this.

So your solution is to implement the differentiation yourself. How to achieve this. I'm not pretending this is the most beautiful solution, but it worked. - we did it by putting a Facade (an EJB itself) (I'm calling it a facade, although it does not entirely cover the facade pattern) in front of all our EJBs, with the following code:

```
public Object call(Object bean,
        String methodName,
        Object[] args,
        Class[] parameterTypes,
        UUID sessionId) throws Throwable {

    //find the session
    SessionContext sessionContext = SessionRegistry.getSession(sessionId);
    //set it as current
    SessionRegistry.setLocalSession(sessionContext);
    .....
}
```

The important parameter is `sessionId` - this is something both the client and the server know about, and identifies the current seesion between them.

On the client we used a dynamic proxy to call this facade. So the calls look like this:
`getBean(MyConcreteEJB.class).someMethod()`, an the getBean method created the proxy, so that callers didn't have to know about the facade bean.

The `SessionRegistry` had

```
private static ThreadLocal<SessionContext> localSessionContext = new 
   ThreadLocal<SessionContext>();
```

And the `SessionContext` was simply a Map providing `set(key, value)` and `get(key)`

So now, instead of using `@Stateful` beans to store your state, you could use the `SessionContext`.

Answer (score 2):

In EJB3.1 you can create your `StatefulOne` bean as singleton (using the `@Singleton` annotation) giving you the desired semantics. JBoss should already support this annotation (they've wrote the standard).

Comment: Wich scope does this singleton have then? Application wide or bound to the client like the stateful bean?

Comment: @Sebastian: Singleton beans are defined to have application wide scope. For session-scope, like you already mentioned, you've got to use session beans instead.