# EJB Visibility from Managed Beans

Tags: ejb

I have Enterprise Java Bean which is Statefull and it holds current user instance
I want to get this instance from few different baking beans (SessionScoped managed beans) but when Im using:

```
@EJB
UserSessionBean usb;

(...)
usb.getUser();
```

I am getting null pointer exceptions in the ManagedBean (seems that every managedbean is getting new instance of UserSessionBean EJB. Why is that? I thought one instance of that bean would be shared among all Beans for that session...

Comment: possible duplicate of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881635/possible-to-inject-same-stateful-session-bean-instance-into-multiple-other-sessi

Answer (score 0):

if UserSessionBean is the implementation class or interface?
I think you should use the interface to create an instance of your EJB.
also take a look at @statefull and @singlton annotations.